# Convert a stored md5 string to a decimal value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, md5, type-conversion

I have a very large table in MySQL. I'm using a CHAR(32) field which contains an MD5 as a string of course. I'm running into an issue where I need to convert this to a decimal value using MySQL. A third party tool runs the query so writing code to do this isn't really an option.

MySQL does support storing hex values natively and converting them to integers. But it gets hung up converting it from a string. Here's what I've tried so far (md5_key is the name of my column)

First I just tried the UNHEX function but that returns a string so it gave me gooblygoop. I won't put that here. Next I tried the CAST function

```
SELECT CAST( CONCAT('0x',md5_key) AS UNSIGNED ) FROM bigtable limit 1
```

Result = 0
Show warnings gives me: "Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '0x000002dcc38af6f209e91518db3e79d3'"

BUT if I do:

```
SELECT CAST( 0x000002dcc38af6f209e91518db3e79d3 AS UNSIGNED );
```

I get the correct decimal value.

So I guess what I need to know, is there a way to get MySQL to see that string as a hex value? (I also tried converting it to BINARY and then to the UNSIGNED but that didn't work either).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

conv() is limited to 64 bit integers. You can convert the high and low part to decimal and then add them together:

```
> select cast(conv(substr("000002dcc38af6f209e91518db3e79d3", 1, 16), 16, 10) as
              decimal(65))*18446744073709551616 +
         cast(conv(substr("000002dcc38af6f209e91518db3e79d3", 17, 16), 16, 10) as
              decimal(65));
58055532535286745202684464101843
```

Where 18446744073709551616 = 2^64. So in your case:

```
> select cast(conv(substr(md5_key, 1, 16), 16, 10) as 
              decimal(65))*18446744073709551616 +
         cast(conv(substr(md5_key, 17, 16), 16, 10) as
              decimal(65))
         from bigtable limit 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Beware MD5 are 16 Byte long, and BIGINT UNSIGNED is 8 Byte long, so even in your second case you don't get the right answer, the number can't fit you are receiving the value of the lowest 8 Byte=> 09e91518db3e79d3.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function to convert big hex numbers to decimal(65).

```
CREATE FUNCTION `hexnum_to_decimal`(hex varchar(66)) RETURNS decimal(65,0)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    declare group1 decimal(65);
    declare group2 decimal(65);
    declare group3 decimal(65);
    declare group4 decimal(65);
    declare multiplier decimal(65);
  
    if (substr(hex, 1, 2) = "0x") then
        set hex = substr(hex, 3); -- trim 0x if exists
    end if;
    
    set hex = trim(LEADING  '0' from hex);
    
    if (length(hex) > 54) then
        return null; -- too big number
    end if;
    
    set hex = lpad(hex, 64, 0);
    
    set group1 = cast(conv(substr(hex, 49, 16), 16, 10) as decimal(65));
    set group2 = cast(conv(substr(hex, 33, 16), 16, 10) as decimal(65));
    set group3 = cast(conv(substr(hex, 17, 16), 16, 10) as decimal(65));
    set group4 = cast(conv(substr(hex,  1, 16), 16, 10) as decimal(65));
    set multiplier = 18446744073709551616; -- 2 ^ 16
    
    -- check for overflow
    if (
        (group4 > 15930919) or
        (group4 = 15930919 and group3 > 2053574980671369030) or
        (group4 = 15930919 and group3 = 2053574980671369030 and group2 > 5636613303479645705) or
        (group4 = 15930919 and group3 = 2053574980671369030 and group2 = 5636613303479645705 and group1 > 18446744073709551615)
    ) then
        return null;
    end if;
    
    return cast(
        group1 +
        group2 * multiplier +
        group3 * multiplier * multiplier +
        group4 * multiplier * multiplier * multiplier
     as decimal(65));
END
```

In your case for 000002dcc38af6f209e91518db3e79d3

```
select hexnum_to_decimal("000002dcc38af6f209e91518db3e79d3");
```

> 58055532535286745202684464101843

```
select hexnum_to_decimal('F316271C7FC3908A8BEF464E3945EF7A253609FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF');
```

> 99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999

if bigger hex number is passed, the function will return null.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately is not possible to convert MD5 into decimal because it will generate a number higher than 2^64-1, however it's possible to create a hash as number based on the MD5 using CRC32.

Example:

```
SELECT concat(conv(left(md5field, 8), 16, 10), CRC32(md5field));
```

The previous example calculate the CRC32 of the MD5 but also concatenate part of the MD5 as a number.
The previous function it fits into MySQL unsigned BigInt but also into a BigQuery Int64 (For BigQuery use better FARM_FINGERPRINT).

The maximum possible number that is possible to generate is 4.294.967.295.400.760.440 if we take "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF" as MD5 hash.

Comment: Thanks for the answer on an old question! We long solved this problem some other way (and now I don't even remember what we did)