# What happend if convert a very large hex to dec using Mysql conv function?

Tags: mysql, decimal, md5

I am using `md5` in Mysql and want to convert the result to decimal, but got this. If I convert the 32-digits hex to dec directly, I got same numbers whatever the hex is. But if I convert lower 8-digits of md5 value only, it seems to be the right result. What happened if I convert a 32-bit hex value?

My code and result is as below:

Query

```
SELECT 
    uid,
    md5(uid),
    conv(md5(uid), 16, 10),
    conv(substring(md5(uid), 25, 8), 16, 10)
FROM
    user
ORDER BY uid
LIMIT 5
```

Table

```
    +-----+----------------------------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------+
    | uid | md5(uid)                         | conv(md5(uid),16,10) | conv(substring(md5(uid), 25, 8), 16, 10) |
    +-----+----------------------------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------+
    | 1   | c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b | 18446744073709551615 | 1869972635                               |
    | 2   | c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c | 18446744073709551615 | 3423897132                               |
    | 3   | eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3 | 18446744073709551615 | 4071078643                               |
    | 4   | a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b7542122c | 18446744073709551615 | 1967264300                               |
    | 5   | e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5 | 18446744073709551615 | 1956845781                               |
    +-----+----------------------------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: The MD5 message-digest algorithm is a widely used cryptographic hash function producing a 128-bit (16-byte) hash value. Not sure what you mean by 32 bits? This question seems to be similar to yours: [Convert a stored md5 string to a decimal value in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924850/convert-a-stored-md5-string-to-a-decimal-value-in-mysql)

Comment: @RyanVincent Yeah, it's 128-bits or 32 digits, not 32-bits. That answer helps, thank you very much.

Comment: MD5 is 128 bits.  `CONV(...)` works in only 64 bits.  So you cannot get it.  Note that 18446744073709551615  is 2**64-1.